# Twitter data decoding

Tags: python-3.x, twitter, unicode, encoding, tweepy

I have a simple code that takes data from Twitter (using Tweepy)
and send it to a text file.

```
class StdOutListener(StreamListener):

    def on_data(self, data):
        with codecs.open("twitter_data.txt", "a", encoding="utf-8") as myfile:
            myfile.write(data)
        return True

    def on_error(self, status):
        print (status)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    l = StdOutListener()
    auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
    stream = Stream(auth, l)

    stream.filter(languages=["iw","he"], track=["SomeHebrewWord"]) # etc
```

OK, so now i get the data from twitter streaming to my file.txt.

One line for example, contain the following text(Hebrew words):

```
"text":"\u05d2\u05dd \u05d0\u05e0\u05d9 \u05d7\u05d5\u05e9\u05d1"
```

The issue is with the "twitter_data.txt" file. I'm trying to send this text in **Hebrew** format to my "twitter_data.txt" file, and i don't know how to do this.

if i just print it in my IDLE python window - like this:

```
print(u'"text":"\u05d2\u05dd \u05d0\u05e0\u05d9 \u05d7\u05d5\u05e9\u05d1"')
```

it works and I can see the Hebrew words.

So how can i "decode" it to Hebrew and send it **as an Hebrew** to the text file? (right now, the twitter_data.txt file contains the data in "\u05d2\u05dd" format..)

Thanks.

Comment: This looks like a JSON API, try reading it with `json.loads`. It is a coincidence that both JSON and Python use `\u` escapes; their string literal formats differ in other ways so you shouldn't use a Python parser to read a JSON file.

Comment: You sir, are a champion. Thanks!! After hours of trying different methods, you solved my problem. Thank you.